# Was any object from Anza's expeditions conserved?

Tags: colonization, archaeology, california, spanish-empire

In the 1770s, [Juan Bautista de Anza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Bautista_de_Anza) led two overland expeditions from Sinaloa to Alta California. The first was for reconnaissance and the second, larger and better known, for the purpose of colonization. Most of Spanish California's founding families came with him on the second expedition, which included chaplain [Pedro Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Font), about 260 settlers and attendant livestock. Today Anza's endeavor is remembered through the [Anza National Historic Trail](https://www.nps.gov/juba/index.htm).

**Was any object carried on either of Anza's expeditions conserved?**

[image: Map of the trail]

Comment: Where have you already looked? Someone at the [Anza-Borrego Research Center](https://anzaborrego.ucnrs.org/) might know about his artifacts. Any of the visitor centers at state parks along Anza's route could have some of his belongings as well.